# Losing data after doing session.invalidate

Tags: java

- session.invalidate() is creating problem.
  -

> I am losing data of the previous session when i am doing session.invalidate().

Comment: and... What is your question?

Comment: *I am losing data* this is no laughing matter

Comment: session.inValidate():
If we are logging then at server side server will create session object

If we are calling session.inValidate() method means we are logged out since session object is destroyed by the server.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera my question is i want to do session.invalidate() after login in application for session fixatation, but i am losing the data of the previous session, so how can i save data of the previous session and also change the session after login.

Answer (score 0):

Session invalidate means , you are terminating the session you created.

For an example, you create a session on page 1 which

```
  / Create a session object if it is already not  created.
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

To get the session id that is assigned to it

```
 System.out.println( session.getId() ); //this will return the string contatining the unique identifier assigned to this session.
```

But if lets say you include 
     
  `session.invalidate();`
On the same page or the page you are directing to . this will kill the session you created ...

I hope this helps. 
Cheers

Comment: No, actually i want to do session.invalidate(), for session fixation, so i am asking how to do invalidate and also save the data of the previous session.

Comment: What? are you trying to do a session fixation attack, or avoid a session fixation vulnerability?